# Unable to scrape all the items of a webPage - selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Selenium code

---

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    import csv
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import os
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    # constant selenium options
    opts=  Options()
    opts.add_argument("--headless")
    opts.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    opts.add_argument('--incognito')
    opts.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

    # first I want a list of all the seasons plus the link of those seasons
    page = "https://www.iplt20.com/teams"
    uClient = uReq(page)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
    teams =[]
    ul = page_soup.find("ul",{"class":"content-grid"})
    #print(ul)
    lis  = ul.findAll("li",{"class":"team-card-grid__item"})
    for li in lis:
        l=[]
        l.append(li.find("h3",{"class":"card__title"}).text)
        try:
            l.append(li.find("div",{"class":"team-card__wins"}).text.strip())
        except:
            l.append('')
            #print(l[0]," doesn't win")
        l.append("https://www.iplt20.com"+li.find("a",{"class":"card"})["href"]+"/squad")
        #print(l)
        teams.append(l)
    print(teams)
    for team in teams:
        team_page = team[2]
        print(team_page)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
        driver.get(team_page)
        print(driver.title)
        team_page_soup = driver.page_source
        team_page_beautify = soup(team_page_soup,features="lxml")
        #print(team_page_beautify)
        driver.save_screenshot(team[0]+".png")
        player_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("playersList")
        players  = player_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        print(players)
        #here I am getting an empty players list
        for player in players:
            print(player.text)
        break
```

---

I need to **scrape** multiple pages in a dynamic way but I am unable to get the list items of the ul with class playersList.
What are the other ways of doing the same.
Also, if you can provide some concise and accurate references from which I can learn more will be great.

Comment: Maybe try adding `opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")` so that you can see everything in the viewport?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and scraping, scraper, scraped) not scrap. To scrap means to throw aay like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the squad from the api. Just a matter of feeding in the team id.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

rows = []
for i in [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 62]:
    squad_api = 'https://cricketapi.platform.iplt20.com/tournaments/22399/squads/%s?matchTypes=ALL' %i

    jsonData = requests.get(squad_api).json()
    teamData = jsonData['ALL']['team']
    
    teamData = { 'team_' + your_key: teamData[your_key] for your_key in teamData.keys() }
    playerData = jsonData['ALL']['players']
    
    print(teamData['team_fullName'])

    for player in playerData:
        player = { 'player_' + your_key: player[your_key] for your_key in player.keys() }
        print('\t',player['player_fullName'])
        row = teamData.copy()
        row.update(player)
        
        rows.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(30).to_string())
    team_id        team_fullName team_shortName team_abbreviation team_type team_primaryColor team_secondaryColor  player_id     player_fullName  player_shortName player_nationality player_dateOfBirth  player_rightArmedBowl  player_rightHandedBat player_bowlingStyle
0         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5        100       Ambati Rayudu          A Rayudu             Indian         1985-09-23                   True                   True            OFF_SPIN
1         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       4944             KM Asif           KM Asif             Indian         1993-07-24                   True                   True         MEDIUM_SEAM
2         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5         25        Dwayne Bravo          DJ Bravo        West Indian         1983-10-07                   True                   True         MEDIUM_SEAM
3         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5        140       Deepak Chahar          D Chahar             Indian         1992-08-07                   True                   True         MEDIUM_SEAM
4         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5         24      Faf du Plessis      F du Plessis      South African         1984-07-13                   True                   True            LEG_SPIN
5         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5        898         Imran Tahir           I Tahir      South African         1979-03-27                   True                   True            LEG_SPIN
6         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       4942  Narayan Jagadeesan      N Jagadeesan             Indian         1995-12-24                   True                   True                 NaN
7         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       1118         Karn Sharma          K Sharma             Indian         1987-10-23                   True                  False            LEG_SPIN
8         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       3746         Lungi Ngidi           L Ngidi      South African         1996-03-29                   True                   True           FAST_SEAM
9         1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       1903    Mitchell Santner         M Santner      New Zealander         1992-02-05                  False                  False            ORTHODOX
10        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5          1            MS Dhoni          MS Dhoni             Indian         1981-07-07                   True                   True         MEDIUM_SEAM
11        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       7123       R Sai Kishore        RS Kishore             Indian         1996-11-06                  False                  False            ORTHODOX
12        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5          9     Ravindra Jadeja          R Jadeja             Indian         1988-12-06                  False                  False            ORTHODOX
13        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5        127       Robin Uthappa         R Uthappa             Indian         1985-11-11                   True                   True                 NaN
14        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       5443     Ruturaj Gaikwad         R Gaikwad             Indian         1997-01-31                   True                   True            OFF_SPIN
15        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       2939          Sam Curran          S Curran            English         1998-06-03                  False                  False         MEDIUM_SEAM
16        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       1745      Shardul Thakur          S Thakur             Indian         1991-10-16                   True                   True         MEDIUM_SEAM
17        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5         14        Suresh Raina           S Raina             Indian         1986-11-27                   True                  False            OFF_SPIN
18        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       1735           Moeen Ali             M Ali            English         1987-06-18                   True                  False            OFF_SPIN
19        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       3834  Krishnappa Gowtham         K Gowtham             Indian         1988-10-20                   True                   True            OFF_SPIN
20        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5        156   Cheteshwar Pujara          C Pujara             Indian         1988-01-25                   True                   True            LEG_SPIN
21        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       9474   Harishankar Reddy           H Reddy             Indian         1998-06-02                   True                   True           FAST_SEAM
22        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       7111    C Hari Nishaanth  C Hari Nishaanth             Indian         1996-08-16                   True                  False            OFF_SPIN
23        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5       7105       Bhagath Varma           B Varma             Indian         1998-09-21                   True                   True            OFF_SPIN
24        1  Chennai Super Kings    Super Kings               CSK         m            FDB913              0081E5        937   Jason Behrendorff     J Behrendorff         Australian         1990-04-20                  False                   True           FAST_SEAM
25        3       Delhi Capitals          Delhi                DC         m            004C93              F83430        135      Ajinkya Rahane          A Rahane             Indian         1988-06-06                   True                   True         MEDIUM_SEAM
26        3       Delhi Capitals          Delhi                DC         m            004C93              F83430         30         Amit Mishra          A Mishra             Indian         1982-11-24                   True                   True            LEG_SPIN
27        3       Delhi Capitals          Delhi                DC         m            004C93              F83430       5433       Anrich Nortje          A Nortje      South African         1993-11-16                   True                   True           FAST_SEAM
28        3       Delhi Capitals          Delhi                DC         m            004C93              F83430       1561          Avesh Khan            A Khan             Indian         1996-12-13                   True                   True           FAST_SEAM
29        3       Delhi Capitals          Delhi                DC         m            004C93              F83430       1113          Axar Patel           A Patel             Indian         1994-01-20                  False                  False            ORTHODOX
```